# Warning: ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido

Tags: php, ftp, conexión

tengo el siguiente código para una conexión FTP.

```
$ftp_server="servidorFTP";
$ftp_user_name="username";
$ftp_user_pass="superpass";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("No se pudo conectar a $ftp_server"); 
$login_result =ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id,true);
if((!$conn_id)||(!$login_result)){ 
    echo "<span styl ='color:#FF0000'><h2>¡La conexión FTP ha fallado!<br/>";
    echo "Intentó conectarse a $ ftp_server para el usuario $ ftp_user_name</h2></span>";
}
```

Resulta que ayer hubo una desconexión de las redes, con tal de que el equipo, no tenía conexión a internet. Y acá viene mi pregunta... 
¿Por que el warning no es contenido por el die()?
Tal parece que el error radica en otro momento y no lo estoy conteniendo.

Comment: Porque `die()` siempre se ejecuta cuando el `ftp_connect()` sea falso( ya que se hace un `or die`), y para que esto sea falso tiene que existir un `error` y no un `warning`

Comment: Como dice la [documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ftp-connect.php): "*Devuelve una secuencia FTP en caso de éxito o false en caso de error*"

Comment: Entonces de que modo puedo contener un error como el descrito ?? Actúo sobre quien ?

Comment: Yo creo que lo mas facil seria usar un `try-catch`

Comment: No que el @ solo cancela los warnings ??

Comment: De hecho no, porque en la [documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) dice "*Una simple regla de oro es: si se puede tomar el valor de algo, entonces se le puede anteponer el operador @*"

Comment: Creo que para tu problema solo es poner eso y ya, creare una respuesta para que veas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de ver el porque, tenemos que saber que devuelve `ftp_connect()`, segun documentacion:

> Devuelve una secuencia FTP en caso de éxito o false en caso de error.

Entonces, esto nos lleva a tu pregunta

**¿Por que el warning no es contenido por el die()?**

- Porque se esta haciendo uso del operador `or` por lo cual esto validara una condicion `true-false`. Quiere decir que `ftp_connect()` tiene que ser falso para que se ejecute el `die()`

Ahora, el modo de contener esto lo veo de 2 formas

**1. Try-Catch:** Lo clasico para capturar esto tipo de casos

```
try {
    ftp_connect($ftp_server);
} catch (Exception $th) {
    return 'Error personalizado';
}
```

**2. @** Si lo que quieres es que muestre siempre el mensaje dentro del `die`, entonces simplemente agrega este operador de control a tu `ftp_connect()`

```
@ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die ("No se pudo conectar a '$ftp_server'");
```

Referencia:

- https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ftp-connect.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php